# Making an web application which allows user to edit html templates and save those templets on server

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery, wysiwyg

I am creating a web-application which lets you select a template from the template list and then user can edit that template on my website by drag and drop and normal wysiwyg editor. Now my question is,

What is the best practise?

1. Create base template in php and keep changing the values of component through ajax calls. or...
2. Manipulate entire template on client side(only using javascript) and while saving, get current state of template and send it onto the server for persistence.(I am not sure this is a viable idea)

Help will be appreciated. Currently I am building all the editing tools like colour palettes and adding NicEdit lightweight text editor. Mostly everything is using Jquery lib so please do let me know if you know a way to tackle this problem through Jquery.

Comment: you can do all that with either timyMCE or cfkeditor

Comment: what about mobile clients, bots, etc. with no or at least less javascript support?

Comment: I don't think there's a "best practice" for such a high level, broad problem. Try listing out advantages and problems with each approach **for your specific situation** and decide for one or the other based on that.

Comment: Ohh ok, Is it really hard to tackle? As I have said yes to my client and this is like a final semester project for me :( . I hope I can finish this on time. But as you mentioned it is a broad problem now I am bit scared

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution can vary based on what exact requirements (including traffic on this app) you are trying to achieve.

If i were to create this from scratch, i will probably choose a hybrid solution:

1. cache template state on client side
2. add handlers on various user events like "typing/paused in textbox", "clicking through your wysiwyg editor menu"
3. when a user has been detected as idle (in context of template state) e.g. he just pressed a upload image button, you can send over an ajax to sync template state in backend

PS: Make sure you add an event on page unload and other related events, so that you make sure you have synced your client side template state with backend, before user leaves the page.